# Is there a standard one time only Post-Deployment action for a Java EE EAR/WAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment

Is there a standard way in an EAR/WAR to declare a post-deployment action?  What I'm after is a script to do some actions after a successful deployment of the EAR to the application server, i.e ONLY once when the EAR is deployed, not each time it's run.  I know that there are a few proprietary extensions that can do this, but I wanted to check there wasn't a "standard" way to do this before I went that way (or just have a documentation step in our instructions).

Comment: I'm new to java, so thank you for clarifying that the two are different technologies!

Comment: Java 7, Wildfly 8.2.

Comment: Thats the startup of the application.  What I'm after is on deployment (once per the deployment of the EAR, not once per execution).

Comment: We need to deploy scripts to the server for custom behaviour (outside of wildlfy).  I only need to do this when the application is deployed to the server.  Right now our instructions are deploy the app and run this special script.  I wanted to know if there was a supported way to do a custom action ONCE per deployment of the EAR, so we didn't have a manual step after deployment.

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the wrong language here.  I am talking about the EAR being "installed, deployed, copied" whatever is the right word to the application server.  This action happens ONCE in the lifetime of the system and each time the software is recompiled and updated.  However the server may be restarted and therefore the @PostConstruct would run AGAIN each time.  What I was after was a run once per deployment, not once per execution.

Comment: my question was: Is there a special annotation that means this, or do I have to code the one time check.